# Unable to use JOIN in an UPDATE query with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo, mysql-error-1064

I've tried every way I can think of, and, according to my research, that there is to use a JOIN statement in an UPDATE query.

```
UPDATE
    `cos` 
INNER JOIN
    `co_types` 
        ON (
            `cos`.`TYPE_ID`=`co_types`.`ID`
        )  
SET
    `cos`.`ARCHIVED` = ? 
WHERE
    `co_types`.`A_ID` = ?;
```

I am using PDO, calling `execute` with `[1, 1]` as parameters.  However, in doing so, I get the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'co_types.A_ID' in 'where clause'
```

I've tried rearranging the query every way I can from what I've found, including:

- Adding a `FROM` clause
- Reordering the clauses around
- Linting my query (success)
- Going to the 3<sup>rd</sup> page of google
- And some other stuff I don't quite remember after 4 hours of this...

The above query is a formatted version, however the raw query being sent is no different except whitespace:

```
UPDATE `cos` INNER JOIN `co_types` ON (`cos`.`TYPE_ID`=`co_types`.`ID`)  SET `cos`.`ARCHIVED` = ? WHERE `co_types`.`A_ID` = ?;
```

Taking either the minified or formatted versions, inserting values manually, and running them in a client such as MySQL's command line or PHPMyAdmin is successful.

Below are my table definitions, shortened for brevity:

```
CREATE TABLE `cos` (
  `ID` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `USER_ID` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `TYPE_ID` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ARCHIVED` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
CREATE TABLE `co_types` (
  `ID` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `A_ID` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

There are more columns and whatnot, however I do not believe they are relevant to the question.

Here are some of the websites I used when initially trying to debug this issue:

- [MYSQL Update Statement Inner Join Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables)
- [sql update with inner join and where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540178/sql-update-with-inner-join-and-where)
- [mysql update query with inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167257/mysql-update-query-with-inner-join)
- [MySql Update A Joined Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331687/mysql-update-a-joined-table)
- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/
- https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?6,156225,156271
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21152/how-to-update-one-table-based-on-another-tables-values-on-the-fly/36664
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41261/update-table-based-on-the-same-table
- http://www.voidtricks.com/mysql-inner-join-update/
- https://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/cross-table-update/
- https://makandracards.com/makandra/32357-postgresql-vs-mysql-how-to-update-using-a-join
- https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-update-from-select-in-sql-server/
- http://www.geeksengine.com/database/data-manipulation/cross-table-update.php
- https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/
- http://emrpms.blogspot.com/2014/12/mysql-update-example-using-group-by-and.html
- http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/56823/delete-update-rows-using-inner-join-sql-server/
- https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic307916-8-1.aspx

However, most of these were somewhat irrelevant.  Regardless, I attempted most all variations that I could.

If anyone could shed some light on why this doesn't work, that'd be great!

---

**Solution:**

Unqualifying the column names fixed my issue:

```
UPDATE
    `cos` 
INNER JOIN
    `co_types` 
        ON (
            `cos`.`TYPE_ID`=`co_types`.`ID`
        )  
SET
    `cos`.`ARCHIVED` = ? 
WHERE
    A_ID = ?;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bet your actual code looks like this:

```
WHERE `co_types.A_ID` = ?`
```

Notice that it has the backticks around both the table and column names, rather than around each of them separately. This prevents the special meaning of the `.` character as a separator between table and column, treating it as a literal character in the column name.

It should be

```
WHERE `co_types`.`A_ID` = ?
```

as in the question. Or just leave out the backticks entirely, they're not needed when the names don't contain special characters.

Comment: The code I shared (`UPDATE \`cos\` INNER JOIN \`co_types\` ON (\`cos\`.\`TYPE_ID\`=\`co_types\`.\`ID\`)  SET \`cos\`.\`ARCHIVED\` = ? WHERE \`co_types\`.\`A_ID\` = ?;`) was exactly what I ran.

Comment: What happens if you change it to `WHERE A_ID = ?`?

Comment: I receive the same `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'co_types.A_ID' in 'where clause'`, which seems strange as I'm not even fully qualifying the column name.

Comment: Yes, that's very strange. How can it know that it shouldn't complain about `cos.A_ID`? Can you turn on query logging in mysqld and see what it logs? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log

Comment: Are there any views involved?

Comment: I hadn't even thought to look at the general log.  Looking at that, I realize I've been an idiot.  I had been trying a bunch of things for the past few hours, and, since the first error with the UPDATE query, assumed all further errors were from it.  Looking at the general log I see it was several later, and that I had fixed my UPDATE query.  I'll post my solution up above and mark your answer as correct.  Thanks for your help!